# Django image compression and resize not working

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I don't understand why this code can't resize image? Why image is uploading it's actual size? here is my code:

**#models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from PIL import Image
    
class Post(SafeDeleteModel):
             header_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="blog/images/", blank= True, null= True)
             
             def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
                  super().save(*args, **kwargs)
                  img = Image.open(self.header_image.path)
        
                  if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
                     out_put_size = (300,300)
                     img.thumbnail(out_put_size)
                     img.save(self.header_image.path)
```

**#root urls.py**

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
        path('',include('blog.urls')),
       
      
    ]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**#forms.py**

```
class BlogPost(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
      model = Post
      fields = ['title','author','body','header_image']
      
      widgets = {
         'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
         'author': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
         'body': RichTextField(),
      }
```

screenshot of my code
**.path** not importing. I think this is the main problem
[image]

my terminal result:
[image]

I aslo want to know how to applay format and quality attribute of PIL in django model. see below:

```
("kenya_buzz_compressed.jpg", format="JPEG", quality=70)
```

Comment: Got any errors?

Comment: didn't get any errors

Comment: also try to use "super(Post).save(*args, **kwargs)" but didn't work

Comment: I checked your code actually it works, I uploaded an image with a larger resolution(width and height greater than 300px) it generates a thumbnail with the same aspect ratio.

Comment: I don't understand why this code is not working. I think  .path is not find the image path.

Comment: can you please show your full code

Comment: I haven't changed anything, just ran your code.. are you expecting a square image as output, if it is so you have to use Image.resize() instead of thumbnail.. the thumbnail just shrink the image keeping the aspect ratio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to generate an image of resolution 300x300, you have to [crop()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.crop) the image after generating [thumbnail()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.thumbnail)

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save()
    img = Image.open(self.header_image.path)
    width, height = img.size  # Get dimensions
    print(f'Original Image Dimenstions: w:{width} h:{height}')

    if width > 300 and height > 300:
        # keep ratio but shrink down
        img.thumbnail((width, height))

    # check which one is smaller
    if height < width:
        # make square by cutting off equal amounts left and right
        left = (width - height) / 2
        right = (width + height) / 2
        top = 0
        bottom = height
        img = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))

    elif width < height:
        # make square by cutting off bottom
        left = 0
        right = width
        top = 0
        bottom = width
        img = img.crop((left, top, right, bottom))

    if width > 300 and height > 300:
        img.thumbnail((300, 300))

    width, height = img.size  # Get new dimensions
    print(f'Cropped Image Dimenstions: w:{width} h:{height}')

    img.save(self.header_image.path)
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw that I don't think the .path is the issue here..

Comment: why ".path" is not importing? do I need to import anything extra ?

Comment: I just added 2 fstrings to check the image resolutions, can you try it and show the terminal output

Comment: see the edited question. after upload photo I am not seeing any print result in my terminal.

Comment: I think function is not calling properly any reason.

Comment: can you copy paste the whole answer including that def save part and try again..

Comment: are you using the latest django?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232389/discussion-between-boyenec-and-sumithran).

Comment: intead of ```super().save()``` try ```super(Post).save()```

Comment: I tried "super(Post).save()" before post the question but didn't work. This is very strange. it's look like everything's correct in my code and not getting any error but image not resizing

Comment: It prevent to delete data from database

Comment: Sumithran the main reason it didn't work for using SafeDeleteModel.  We must be use models.Model

Comment: finally got the culprit :)

Comment: yeah :)))...Thnak you for your patients. do you know how to use  format="JPEG", quality=70 those attribute in django model ?

Comment: actually, Django has nothing to do with format and quality it is the attribute of Pillow.. you can pass these attributes in save() method of image instance

Comment: how to get custom image Hight and Width? such as I want to set image width 1000px and Hight 400px. any idea ?